# Generate android layout from RN component JSX/Styles

Tags: android, react-native

I want to convert a react native component (JSX and its styles) to an android component (layout xml and, if available, the java class).

I am aware RN doesn't compile js to java/byte code, therefore i am interested only in the UI portion of the code.

I tried to diff the files generated in android folder, to see where my changes to the RN component are being generated after a compile, but seems like the changes affect only a js file `"\android\app\build\intermediates\assets\release\index.android.bundle"` (in addition to the apk ofc)

- Where does react native compile components? (memory??)
- How does RN compile components to layouts and styles?
- Is it possible to strip down react native source to only generate the "presentational" part of android, or is there any library/attempt (i am unaware of) to achieve such a thing?

Comment: want to convert the android layout to react native component